# Select option value using php

Tags: php, html, date

I need select option like below format using php

```
<select>
<option value="2011-2012">2011-2012</option>
<option value="2012-2013">2011-2012</option>
<option value="2013-2014">2011-2012</option>
<option value="2014-2015">2011-2012</option>
<option value="2015-2016">2011-2012</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what you tried so for? your code?

Comment: Those times when not even a single microsecond of research was shown, no question is asked in the *actual question* and only a command is given...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `foreach` to achieve this:

```
<select>
    <?php $years = array('2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015');
    foreach ($years as $year) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>"><?php echo $year; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: the date is dynamic field.

Comment: @Ajin You didn't say that in the question... I'm sure you can apply the same principle as I've done above to get it working the way you need...

Answer (score 0):

```
$years = range(date("Y"), 2006);
$yearsplus = range(date("Y", strtotime('+1 years')), 2006);

$yearrange = new MultipleIterator();
$yearrange->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($years));
$yearrange->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($yearsplus));

foreach($yearrange as $values) {
    $result[] = $values;
}
echo "<select>";
foreach ($result as $res) {
    echo '<option value="'.$res[0].'-'.$res[1].'">'.$res[0].'-'.$res[1].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```